# Handling possibility of empty parseInt

Tags: java, parseint

I have a String, and I successfully extract the **text** between two special characters.

*(My **text** are numbers, example -- hi%773%what -- i get 773)*

I use praseInt to change my substring of numbers into an integer(which is successful).

Where my program crashes and burns (*praseInt numformat exception)* ,
is when my string contains no numbers between the special characters.

> my_String = "heyhow$**98765**$you" **Works, I get 98765 and can easily parseInt**
>
> .
>
> my_String = "heyhow$$areyou"  **Runtime Error**
>
> .

```
String str = "heyhow$$areyou";
int startIndex = str.indexOf('$');
int lastIndex = str.indexOf('$', i+1);
String nums = str.substring(startIndex + 1, lastIndex);
int stringNumber = Integer.parseInt(nums); <--runtime error cause of no# to parse
```

Thank you in advance for any help. If you have an idea that does not involve using a loop or conditional statement that would be the best!

Comment: int stringNumber = (nums!=null?Integer.parseInt(nums):0);

Comment: What do you want to happen when your string contains no numbers between the special characters? You'll have to either use some conditional statement/expression or catch the exception.

Comment: Why only check for empty value. What if input is `"try$this$out"`? Value would be `"this"`, and that will fail too.

Comment: Sorry I did not add that! I would really like the value of 0 to be assigned.

Comment: @Rahul nums can't be null...

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
int stringNumber = nums.length() > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(nums) : 0;
```

This will parse the number if its length is not zero, otherwise it will set `stringNumber` to the value `0`.  Change it if you want a different value for an empty string.

This will still fail if the string between the delimiters is not a valid number.  If that is a possibility:

```
int stringNumber = 0;
try {
    stringNumber = Integer.parseInt(nums);
}
catch (NumberFormatException nx)
    // depends on how you want to handle invalid numbers
}
```

Comment: nums.length() will throw NPE if nums==null

Comment: `str.substring()` cannot return null.

Answer (score 0):

Java ternary operator can be used nicely as below:

```
int stringNumber = (!nums.isEmpty() ?Integer.parseInt(nums):0);
```

Comment: This works great as well! I needed the return of 0 so I could know there was nothing in between the characters.

Comment: what if the number is legitimately 0?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is a regular expression, so any bad data between your markers are detected:

```
private static int extractInt(String input) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\$([0-9]+)\\$").matcher(input);
    if (! m.find())
        return 0;
    return Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
}
```

See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/bDVG1l) for demo.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "heywhatsgoing$$youtoday";
int startIndex = str.indexOf('$');
int lastIndex = str.indexOf('$', startIndex+1);
String nums = str.substring(startIndex + 1, lastIndex);
int stringNumber = nums.length() > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(nums) : 0;
```

This gave me a value of 0.

This answer handled the possibility of the exception **AND** gave me a specific value I could use to handle that exception.

Thank you to everyone who took the time to look at this.

Comment: "This answer handled the possibility of the exception" - that's not right; if you provide text instead of a number, your code will still throw an exception. In any case, while self-answering is alright, you need to provide attribution of you take somebody else's answer and incorporate it in yours.